# unable to add row into jTable in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, netbeans-8

I'am trying to access data from database and showing it in jTable on clicking a button. but my table shows nothing on pressing button. i have gone through all adding row into table questions in stackOverflow but nothing helped me. here i'am pasting my button's actionListener-

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    java.util.Date utildate = jDateChooser1.getDate();
    java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(utildate.getTime());
    //System.out.println(date);

    String dbURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/contact;user=nbuser;password=nbuser";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try
    {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver").newInstance();;
        //Get a connection
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL); 
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        //System.out.println(id);
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("select ID, NAME from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY ID "); 
        ArrayList<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        Map<String, String> present = new HashMap<String, String>();
        while(result.next()){
        id.add(result.getString("id"));
        name.add(result.getString("name"));
        present.put(result.getString("id"), "A");
        }
        result = stmt.executeQuery("select ID from ATTENDANCE where DATE = '" + date +"'");
        while(result.next()){
            present.replace(result.getString("id"), "P");
        }
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(new String[] { "Id", "Name","Attendance"});
        for(int i = 0; i < id.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(id.get(i)+" "+ name.get(i)+ " "+ present.get(id.get(i)));
            model.addRow(new String[]{id.get(i), name.get(i), present.get(id.get(i))});
            model.fireTableRowsInserted(1, i+1);
        }
        jTable1.setModel(model);
    }
    catch (Exception except)
    {
        except.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please tell me where i'am doing wrong?

Comment: are there any logs?
In My system I can see the table. Can you please add `System.out.println("In jButton4ActionPerformed")` in first line of method to check whether it is executing that method or not

Comment: i'am printing the values while adding row in jtable. and output is coming in console.u can see the System.out.println... in the above code.

Comment: did you run the same code in your system?

Comment: please paste your code here. it can help me.. :)

Comment: You code doesn't show where you add the table to a JScrollPane and the scrollPane to the frame. If you are changing the data of the table that has been added to the frame then you should see the data.